# VSTS no longer adds build number to Global List upon build complete?

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

I am using VSTS build & release feature to build the .net project. After building the project, I want build number to be updated in the Global List so that I can select the same build number to resolve the defects (Integrated in Build) and while executing the test cases through MTM.

This feature was present when we were using in-premise TFS 2013.

Please let me know if there is a way to update the build no. in the Global List using VSTS Rest API.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1):

There isn’t the Rest API to update the Global List, you can update the Global List by using VSTS/TFS client API ([WorkItemStore.ImportGlobalLists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitemstore.importgloballists(v=vs.120).aspx) Method) or [witadmin commands](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/reference/witadmin/manage-global-lists-for-work-item-types).

A sample by using PowerShell: [Get TfsCollection and TFS Services](https://nkdagility.com/powershell-tfs-2013-api-1-get-tfscollection-and-tfs-services/) and [Adding to a GlobalList](https://nkdagility.com/powershell-tfs-2013-api-2-adding-to-a-globallist/).

```
function Add-TfsGlobalListItem {
    Param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection] $TfsCollection,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String] $GlobalListName,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String] $GlobalEntryValue
        )
    # Get Global List
    $store = Get-TfsWorkItemStore $TfsCollection
    [xml]$export = $store.ExportGlobalLists();

    $globalLists = $export.ChildNodes[0];
    $globalList = $globalLists.SelectSingleNode("//GLOBALLIST[@name='$GlobalListName']")

    # if no GL then add it
    If ($globalList -eq $null)
    {
        $globalList = $export.CreateElement("GLOBALLIST");
        $globalListNameAttribute = $export.CreateAttribute("name");
        $globalListNameAttribute.Value = $GlobalListName
        $globalList.Attributes.Append($globalListNameAttribute);
        $globalLists.AppendChild($globalList);
    }

    #Create a new node.
    $GlobalEntry = $export.CreateElement("LISTITEM");
    $GlobalEntryAttribute = $export.CreateAttribute("value");
    $GlobalEntryAttribute.Value = $GlobalEntryValue
    $GlobalEntry.Attributes.Append($GlobalEntryAttribute);

    #Add new entry to list
    $globalList.AppendChild($GlobalEntry)
    # Import list to server
    $store.ImportGlobalLists($globalLists)
```

On the other hand, you can refer to this article to update related work item of build: [Build association with work Items in vNext](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2016/05/09/build-association-with-work-items-in-vnext/)

Update:

Simple code to connect to VSTS:

```
param(
    [string]$address,
    [string]$username,
    [string]$password
    )
$credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username, $password)
$tfsCollection = New-Object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection((New-Object System.URI($address)))
    $wis = $tfsCollection.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore])
```

Then, you can specify the arguments in PowerShell task (build or release) Arguments textbox `-address XXX -username XXX -password XXX`. (The username can be empty and use personal access token as password)

On the other hand, you can import the assemblies files that in [Microsoft Team Foundation Server Extended Client package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/).

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution. How to pass the credentials with $TfsCollection URI in the power shell?

Comment: @DeepakGarg Another part of that article is https://nkdagility.com/powershell-tfs-2013-api-1-get-tfscollection-and-tfs-services/, I also updated my answer with a simple code to connect to VSTS. Note: you need to specify the username and password, if you want to do it during the build or release.